# Missing directive or assembly reference for ReadElementString

Tags: c#, xml

I can not seem to use the ReadElementString while using a System.XML.XmlReader object.
I get the following error:

> 'System.Xml.XmlReader' does not contain a definition for
>   'ReadElementString' and  no extension method 'ReadElementString'
>   accepting a first argument of type  'System.Xml.XmlReader' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an  assembly reference?)

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;

public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
{
    this.pKidsID = reader.GetAttribute("KidsID");
    reader.MoveToContent();
    reader.ReadStartElement();
    this.FirstName = reader.ReadElementString("FirstName");
    this.Name = reader.ReadElementString("Name");
    reader.Read();
    reader.ReadEndElement();
}
```

Here is an example of my xml file. Can you tell me how to use Linq to XML to read this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Kids>
  <Child>
    <Name>kidone</Name>
    <FirstName>elmo</FirstName>
  </Child>
  <Child>
    <Name>kidtwo</Name>
    <FirstName>elmo</FirstName>
  </Child>
</Kids>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your project references and add a reference to the `System.Xml.dll` file. Since you already have a `using System.Xml;` directive, I suspect the dll isn't referenced.

From the Solution Explorer menu, select References and it will show all the referenced files. Right click it and select "Add Reference..." then add the `System.Xml.dll` file. Alternately, you can do this from the Project menu.

Apart from that the code you posted looks incomplete since it isn't contained within a class, but I guess you didn't share the full code.

Comment: thx for replying to my question. I will check the references, i thought that the using statment would be enough.

Comment: The references are good but it still gives me the error. Is it possible that the ReadElementString extension method is not available in the Windows Phone v7.1 framework ?

Comment: @user717316 Yes, that makes a difference. WP7 uses XNA/Silverlight, based on the .NET Compact Framework. On MSDN you can select any class and inspect the supported methods based on the icons displayed next to each one (hover with your mouse to see the alt text). If you visit the class or method itself, underneath the name you should see an "Other Versions" dropdownlist, and for [`ReadElementString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef1hfxb9.aspx) you'll notice that "Silverlight" isn't an option. That said, LINQ to XML is supported, so it should be possible to use that instead.

Comment: @user717316 if you're open to using LINQ to XML then share an example of the XML you're working with (edit your original post) and I can show you how to read it.

Comment: I have edited my original post. Sorry for the late response ;-)